# Data Flow Testing Tool/Software

Tags: automated-testing, tools, open-source

I am looking for data flow testing tool/software. I have searched many times on  the internet. But, I couldn't find any of them to fulfill my requirements. For example, [Pestt](http://pestt.github.io/), this tool for control flow testing. Tool/software I'm looking for is described as follow:

1. It's free or open source,
2. It has documentation and tutorial,
3. Desktop or web-based application, and
4. Programming language for testing doesn't matter.
5. I desire if the tool can generate data flow graph from given source code program, test requirements, test path, and coverage result in statistic.

If anyone know the tool/software, but it doesn't meet my description. Feel free to post a comment.

Summary of **data flow testing** can be found [here](http://www.khannur.com/stb6.2.htm).

Comment: What about this - http://help.pervasive.com/display/DF62/Installing+the+Dataflow+Eclipse+IDE+Plugin?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @LittlePanda.
By the way, what it looks like? 
I am looking for data flow testing tool that can generate data flow graph, test requirements, and coverage result in statistic. If they don't exist, data flow anomaly checker is OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage data flow testing using Mindmap Tool.

Edraw Mind Map is a free mind map software with rich examples and templates which make it easy to create mind maps, brain-storming diagrams, project timeline, life planner, SWOT analysis and sketch maps. Check more details in Edraw Site

Please check this tool [EDraw](https://www.edrawsoft.com/freemind.php)

Also check http://www.wisemapping.com/